# Eclipse web service client Service call error "There is no authentication Header"

Tags: eclipse, axis, soapui, webservice-client, visualrules

There is a web service deployed on the execution
 server the execution server requires authentication on service call.

I have created a web service client in eclipse by pointing the url of wsdl of required service.

But the service call generates **exception below**..

> faultSubcode:
>
> faultString: There is no security header.
>
> This is needed for authentication against Identity Management.
>
> faultActor:
>
> faultNode:
>
> faultDetail:

```
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:There is no security header. This is** needed for authentication against Identity Management.
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at com.visual_rules.www.vrpath.Dummy.DummyBindingStub.dummy_dummy(DummyBindingStub.java:213)
at com.visual_rules.www.vrpath.Dummy.DummyProxy.dummy_dummy(DummyProxy.java:50)
at Main$1.run(Main.java:230)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:HO-D-0047
```

If I am calling this service from SoapUi same error comes.

**I have added the security header to the request as**

> qName= new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
>                       "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
>   "Security");
>               org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement header = new org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement(qName);
>               header.setActor(null);
>               header.setMustUnderstand(true);

```
// Add the UsernameToken element to the WS-Security header
        javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement utElem;
        try {
            utElem = header.addChildElement("UsernameToken");

        utElem.setAttribute("Id", "uuid-3453f017-d595-4a5b-bc16-da53e5831cd1-1");
        javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement userNameElem = utElem.addChildElement("Username");
        userNameElem.setValue("Admin");
        javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement passwordElem = utElem.addChildElement("Password");
        passwordElem.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");

        passwordElem.setValue("Password");
```

But still not working, **now the error is**

> faultSubcode:
>
> faultString: The attribute 'Type' on element 'ns1:Password' is
>   missing or inccorect
>
> faultActor:**

Please Reply

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another value for the "Type" attribute:

```
<wsse:Password Type="http://www.visual-rules.com/wss#PasswordText">
```

It's documented in the Execution Server 6 manual in chapter 6.1.1 Authentication for Rule Service Call.